# I want create logic codes, but i dont know where, in right folder of module

Tags: magento

Guys I want create files for check somethings, and create my owner custom rules, in my module, like:

```
if($car == green) {
    return true;
}
```

or

```
protected function setMyCustomMethod(){
    $today = Mage::getResouceModel('namespace/module');

    if($today == friday) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

but i dont know where i can create this files, and where i do my logical... just for rules and check so conditions....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Magento universe you'd create a helper object in your module, and put your logic checking methods on that helper.  Then, when you needed to use it, you'd instantiate the helper and call the methods.